# error CS1069: The type name 'ZipArchive' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression'

Tags: unity, c#, dll

When I build my project, which references the `System.IO.Compression` namespace, the build succeeds without issue inside Visual Studio.

However, inside the Unity editor, I see the following error:

```
error CS1069: The type name 'ZipArchive' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

I added a `csc.rsp` file inside my Assets folder, with the following line:

```
-r:System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

Unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue.

Here are the properties of the `System.IO.Compression` DLL that I reference inside Visual Studio:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I personally haven't ever had the need to do anything like this. But did you take a look at [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-compression-zip-missing.577492/)? As it looks like this person had the same problem as you.

Comment: This could be a similar issue when using JSON.Net. Try putting the dll file from the C:\Program Files (x86)\... path into your project folder inside Assets\Plugins. Create the folder Plugins if it does not exist. I can add this as an answer if it works for you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Try to replace the

```
-r:System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

with

```
-r:System.IO.Compression.dll
```

in the `crc.rsp` file.

P.S.

You can also try to add

```
-r:System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

to that file too.

Comment: you are a genius!